# CSS: how to have a max height in datalist?

Tags: html, css, web, bootstrap-4

i have this datalist and i am assuming that data in options has morethan 100, and I want to have a max height so that the design looks neat. please help me to guys. thank you.

```
<input type="text" list="suggestions" class="form-control" style="width: 100%;" >
<datalist id="suggestions" >
  <option value="Blue">
  <option value="White">     
  <option value="Black">
  <option value="Red">
  <option value="Green">
  <option value="Blue">
  <option value="White">     
  <option value="Black">
  <option value="Red">
</datalist>
```

Comment: I think you need to add more details/example to clarify what you're asking

Answer (score -1):

Do you want a scrollable div to show all the options?
If yes, you can set the height of the parent 'div' to a set height and set the "overflow-y:auto" .